# ADOTable IndexName

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I have written a small Windows VCL application. It connects to SQL Server Express using an ADOTable through an ADOConnection. I can see data. The program complies and runs.

In the object browser - when I click on ADOTable.IndexName property it gives me the indexes for the table.  But when I try to select one, I get - **Current provider does not support the necessary interface for Index functionality.**

If I try to set the ADOTable.IndexName property at runtime I get the same message.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Use an ADOQuery instead, and use the ORDER BY clause in the SQL statement to order the data. Tables are not really useful when dealing with RDBMSs, which don't allow selection of indexes the way you're trying to use them. Alternately, use a ClientDataSet (CDS) which you fill from the ADOTable or ADOQuery, and then create the indexes on that CDS instead.